# jQuery and Plugin Namespacing and Inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, namespaces

Hey guys. There has been a lot of activity lately on the jQuery Dev Group about prototypal inheritance and plugin namespacing, and I want to see who has the best answer for it.

Group link:
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/620c6a18a16d9665

Questions:

What do you guys think should be done about this and why?
Do you agree with any opinions there? Why or why not?

Why it is important:

If jQuery did decide to implement something like this into the core, this is a huge decision that will affect a lot of people and may affect how they use/extend jQuery and *if* they continue to use jQuery. It may convert a lot of people *to* jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I think what sets jQuery apart from libraries like prototype is that it concentrates on features such as fast DOM selection, traversal and manipulation rather than adding 'flavor' to javascript.

Problem with Prototype is it puts a ruby hat on javascript and it ends up getting bloated with features you probably never end up using.

I have worked in projects where people overuse prototype Classes to implement everything as a class where it simply wasn't needed. People who move from Java or C# (or even Ruby) like to do everything their way - which is often not needed.

Comment: I see Prototype as being a more app-development oriented JS framework, so it works for those types of people. I used it for a while before switching to jQuery (which I find much better for UI/UX).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is important step for jQuery. Of cause jQuery is very dom centric lbrary. And that is why it achieves so much attention over the world, but it is hard to build complex solutions basing on it only. You can not use all the benefits of OOP and so you must to have all the code in a head - all of your programmers must.  I suppose jQuery is the most easy solution - thats why everybody likes it, but now it wants to be enterprise solution.
I think this can make enterprise client side development faster and that is great:)